# phpmyadmin insert csv files

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
"99999999","99999999","AA","AAA","COUNTRYA"
"99999998","99999998","BB","BBB","COUNTRYB"
```

i have changed the values because they are private.
I have made 5 columns in php myadmin in my table. Then i click import and upload the csv file, but i don't know what to fill in the options:

Fields terminated by:

Fields enclosed by:

Fields escaped by:

My question? What do i need to fill in these options to insert my csv file in my table with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly phpmyadmin is not a very secure web app - please try and use a tunneled mysql client.

And to answer your question it is asking for the format of your file.

"Fields terminated by" is asking what separates your fields, in this case the comma does

"Fields enclosed by" is asking for the borders of the field values, in this case the quote is

"Fields escaped by" is asking how you would represent the enclosure character (quote) if you need to use it in the field, in this case it should be `\"`

Comment: if that's the case see if you can enable a SSL connection - even a self signed certificate, because every bit of data you put through phpmyadmin can be sniffed from your computer to the server.